# problems calculating optimal portfolio weights

Tags: r, portfolio, equations

I want to use following formula to calculate optimal weights of allocation; w= Er*(λΣ)^(-1).

ER is a vector of excess returns 1 x 3
λ is an constant parameter, let's say it 6.
Σ is a variance-covariance matrix 3 x 3

below ive tried to code this but i cant make it work. 
can someone help me??

```
w <- solve(as.numeric(Er) %/% solve(as.numeric(λ) * Σ))
```

Comment: What's the error? In the text `ER is a vector of excess returns`, do you mean `Er`? And by `%/%` do you mean matrix multiplication? I believe that's `% * %`. If you posted some example variables and expected output, it would be much easier to help. `% / %` seems to be integer divide.

Comment: yes, I mean Er. answering to matrix question the only matrix is Σ.  
I dont know if its right to use matrix multiplication in this case, that's part of the reason im asking how to do this.
 
favourable output should be allocation weights to all the 3 asset, letts say asset A,B and C forming Er, the vector of expectations.

Comment: You could code your equation as `w <- ( solve(sigma)%*%Er)/lambda` .  Sigma should be a positive definite matrix.